# Matlab for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop

Can someone please help me with my homework.

```
    %this is the function
    f= @(x) 4*e^(-x.^2/4)*sin(x);

    %interval [a,b]
    a=0;
    b=3;

    m=[1 5 20];
    n=2*m;


    for i = 1:3
       h(i) = (b-a)/n(i);
    end;


    for i = 1:3        
        number_points = max(n)+1;
        points=zeros(3,st_tock);
        for j = 1:(n(i) + 1)
            points(i,j) = a + (j-1)*h(i);
        end
    end;
```

This last "for loop" doesn't work correctly.

It may helps if you read this first:    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson's_rule..
I'm doing an algorithm for Composite Simpson's rule.

My homework is to integrate function f(x) = 4*e^(-x.^2/4)*sin(x) with this rule for m=1,m=5 and m=20. Points are equidistant -->  h=(b-a)/(2*m) and x_i = a + i*h.
(m is number of parts of the interval [a,b] which is [0,3]. For example: if m=1, then n=2 and we get x1,x2 and x3. When m=5, n=10 and we get x1,...x11 and when m=20 we get x1,...,x41)

So first I defined h(i) (first for loop is ok), because I want to get points x1,x2,...
And then I created an empty matrix 3x41 dimension and define each point separately.
Now I want to change zeros in the matrix of zeros-  in first row I want points for m=1, in second row points for m=5 and in third (the last) points for m=20, so the first row will be 0, 1.5, 3, 0,0,0,...., the second row will be 0, 0.3, 0.6, 0.9,..., 2.7, 3, 0,0,0,0,0,... And the third row will not have any zeros except for the first element because a is 0.
 I wanted to put each element separately in this matrix because when I figure out this step i will need this points to solve this integral, but it doesn't work. The last for loop create a matrix and the last row is ok, but the first and second is all zeros. I don't know how to fix this problem.

This is the algorithm for calculating the values of points in function f(x). (when I fix the first one). Do you think it's ok?

```
    for i = 1:3
        number_points = max(n)+1;
        values=zeros(3,number_points);
        for j=1:41
            element = points(i,j);
            value = f(element);
            values(i,j) = value;
        end
    end
```

I hope you understand my problem. If not, let me know what you don't understand and I will try to explain it to you.

Thanks!:)

Comment: Maybe it's because you re-initialize `points` to 0 inside the for loop. If you move the statement `points=zeros(3,st_tock);` two lines higher, it should work.

Comment: at the very least, use a more helpful title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it's not working is because you are **resetting** the `values` array for each iteration of `i`.  Place the `values = zeros(3, number_points);` statement **outside** of the outer most `for` loop.

In other words, do this:

```
values=zeros(3,number_points);
number_points = max(n)+1;

for i = 1:3
    for j=1:41
        element = points(i,j);
        value = f(element);
        values(i,j) = value;
    end
end
```

FWIW: I moved the `number_points` statement outside as well, as this statement never changes in each of the outer most iterations for the first `for` loop.